# Может ли союз И связывать причастный и деепричастный обороты?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, деепричастный-оборот, причастный-оборот

Но, шумом бала утомленный И утро в полночь обратя, Спокойно спит в тени блаженной Забав и роскоши дитя (А.С. Пушкин).

Как объяснить отсутствие запятой перед союзом И? Может ли союз И связывать причастный и деепричастный обороты?

Возможно, это авторская пунктуация. А по современным правилам можно поставить запятую перед союзом И, обособив деепричастный оборот отдельно?

Comment: Возможно, здесь и к грамматике фразы можно придраться. Однородные причастный и деепричастный обороты?! Причастный относится к подлежащему, деепричастный к сказуемому... Но стих так естественно "поётся", что это совершенно незаметно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, по современным правилам союз И тут неуместен. Обороты никак не связаны друг с другом, относятся к разным словам.

И еще. *Утомленный дитя* - это тоже неверно по современным правилам.