# Союз «и» между причастным и деепричастным оборотом. Запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, и, причастный-оборот

В Нацкорпусе случайно попалось вот такое предложение:
Девушка-связистка, удивлённая длинной паузой **и** ожидая раската хриплого генеральского голоса, опасливо поглядела на Захарова, **―** он стоял, приложив платок к глазам. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]

Грамотно ли соединять причастный и деепричастный обороты союзом "и"?
[Похожий вопрос уже задавался ([Может ли союз И связывать причастный и деепричастный обороты?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445000/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%98-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B)) — но в нем рассматривалось предложение А. С. Пушкина. Единственный ответ мне показался неубедительным. Да и "наше" предложение — посовременнее будет.]

А еще меня заинтересовала запятая перед тире — каким правилом руководствовался автор?
Подскажите, правильно ли оформлено предложение? Как бы вы его написали?

P. S. Проверила [здесь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=WTvLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0,%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0,%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=s42AV4jYD1&sig=ACfU3U11dvLhfRjYRynFsBS7vB0ThQ_bag&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAhbOlnr_tAhVqxIsKHVEKD8gQ6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false) и [здесь](https://knijky.ru/books/zhizn-i-sudba?page=17).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В Нацкорпусе случайно попалось вот такое предложение:
>
> *Девушка-связистка, удивлённая длинной паузой и ожидая раската хриплого генеральского голоса, опасливо поглядела на Захарова, ― он
> стоял, приложив платок к глазам.* [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба,
> ч. 1 (1960)]
>
> Грамотно ли соединять причастный и деепричастный обороты союзом "и"?

Розенталь хотя и поместил подобные примеры в параграф с названием "Ошибки в сочетании однородных членов", тем не менее сумел найти им объяснение:

> **§ 208.** <…> Встречающееся у писателей соединение в качестве однородных членов причастного и деепричастного оборотов связано с
> возможностью сближения их значений в условиях контекста, например:
> *Отец, вздохнув и очевидно смущённый, весьма скоро прервал свою речь…* (Л. Толстой); *Растроганный видом этой красивой группы и не желая
> мешать влюблённым, я хотел уже пройти мимо них* (Куприн).
>
> Источник: http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlvi.html

Ну а по поводу запятой и тире…

Розенталь пишет (см. **§ 46**), что в практике печати постановка запятой и тире в качестве единого знака **не ограничивается предусмотренными правилами случаями**.

В частности:

> 2. Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, из которых вторая носит присоединительный характер с
>    каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным,
>    условно-следственным и др.); нередко эта часть начинается
>    местоименными словами *тот, так, такой* и т. п. …
> 3. Запятая и тире ставятся для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной конструкции, для указания, «с одной стороны, на расчлененность
>    предложения, а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за
>    этим знаком препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей
>    части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, “углом”», например  <…>
>    *Марья села на траву, положила голову Мишки к себе на колени, — у него голова висела, до того был худ* (А. Т.)...
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_46.htm

Думается, к рассматриваемому нами предложению может подойти пункт 3.

Comment: *Не знаю, какой из этих пунктов больше подходит к рассматриваемому нами предложению… Может, и оба подходят.* - Я за то, которое у Р. под номером 3. Как сюда притянуть №2 как-то не очень понимаю, тут совсем не пояснение или что-то ему подобное.

Comment: behemothus, согласен. Я и пример-то из Розенталя, более-менее похожий на рассматриваемое нами предложение, именно из №3 и взял. Но уж что написано пером... Хотя, может, убрать всё же №2 из ответа?

Comment: Не думаю, что имеет смысл что-то кардинально править. Я бы более чем удовлетворился замечанием типа "По авторскому пониманию здесь, видимо, имеет место №3".

Comment: @slava1947 Благодарю Вас, Слава (Вы разрешили так обращаться), за квалифицированный ответ. Вот теперь почти все точки над i расставлены.

Answer (score 3):

1. В данном случае **можно допустить такие однородные отношения** между причастным и деепричастным оборотом, так как они **наилучшим образом описывают ситуацию**. Генерал уже говорил по линии связи и вдруг замолчал, девушка  удивлена паузой, но при этом ждет продолжения речи. И все происходит **в один период время (сближение признаков по Розенталю)**, это важно было изобразить, по-другому не получится.
2. Запятая и тире как единый знак надо отнести **к «структурному повороту».** Там тоже **интересная ситуация.** Сначала автор «смотрит» на девушку и рассказывает о ее переживаниях, а потом переводит взгляд (как бы вместе с ней) на генерала. Как обозначить такие отношения между частями в БСП? Присоединительными их не назовешь, здесь основное развитие темы – скорее два разных блока.
3. **Интонация у единого знака** не очень ясная, он похож на нечто среднее между двоеточием и тире (я так думаю). Голос понижается, но не до конца, предупреждая о последующем продолжении темы, как и при двоеточии. Но по длительности пауза короче, она как у тире.

Answer (score 2):

> Грамотно ли соединять причастный и деепричастный обороты союзом "и"?

Мне кажется, вопрос так ставить нельзя. Речь должна идти о **грамматической** правильности, а не о какой-то "грамотности" вообще.  А грамматика в принципе, пусть это и нечастый в практике случай, допускает соединение совершенно разных частей речи в однородные ряды, если такие части речи выступают в качестве близких семантико-грамматических функциях. В данном случае (судя по всему - и вообще в большинстве случаев, когда в такой ряд соединяются деепричастные обороты с определительными конструкциями) такое становится возможным в силу того, что причастный и деепричастный обороты можно трактовать как **обстоятельства причины**.

Остальное - у @slava1947. У него же и про тире с запятой, не буду повторять.

Answer (score 2):

**Дополнение**

Отвечающие интересно рассуждали о грамматике, попробую добавить несколько слов на эту тему.

Я люблю грамматику, мне нравится изучать логический строй языка,  но в душе **я все-таки писатель.** Поэтому, анализируя текст, я представляю себя на его месте и всегда беру его сторону.  Писатель должен знать грамматику или скорее понимать  ее на уровне интуиции. Но **грамматика – это только средство, инструмент в его руках**, главное же – это создать правдивый **художественный образ**. Нужно, чтобы читатель увидел и почувствовал всё то, что видит он, изображая различные  события. И конечно, для анализа нужен **контекст**, иначе вообще сложно делать какие-то выводы.

**На нефтехранилищах произошел крупный пожар.** Начальник штаба Сталинградского фронта Захаров лично пришел на узел связи, чтобы переговорить с Чуйковым (командующим 62-й армией). Там дежурная сказала, что с ним нет связи – ни телефонной, ни телеграфной, ни беспроволочной.  «С дивизиями?» – отрывисто спросил Захаров… Начальник штаба дивизии доложил ему о пожаре на нефтебаках, о том, что огненный вал обрушился на командный пункт штаба армии, что у дивизии нет связи с командармом. Захаров, выслушав начальника штаба, проговорил: «Передайте Чуйкову, если он жив, передайте Чуйкову…»  – и замолчал.
**Девушка-связистка, удивленная длинной паузой и ожидая раската хриплого генеральского голоса, опасливо поглядела на Захарова, – он стоял, приложив платок к глазам.**

**Вот картина.** Девушка обеспечивает связь на линии, где происходит разговор. Она побаивается генерала. У него тяжелое дыхание, властный голос, который вдруг  внезапно прерывается. **Она ждет продолжения начатой фразы** (что же передать?), но пауза почему-то затягивается, кажется странной. Наконец она решается взглянуть на Захарова… Это **не воспоминания о событиях, а «живой» рассказ**, где читатель присутствует вместе с автором. Здесь нельзя ослаблять **напряженность** момента, затягивать описание. Говоря о паузе в речи, нужно одновременно изобразить **и ожидание, и нарастающее удивление**.

Как же это сделать?  Использовать одинаковые  (правильные) конструкции? Например **удивленная и ожидающая**. Но получается вялое и книжное описание. Деепричастие лучше передает движение, так как обозначает признак действия, а не предмета. Даже **разная структура** прибавляет фразе энергичность и стремительность.

**Не согласны? Тогда попробуйте написать (это предложение) лучше.**

Comment: Думается, что «лучше» и «точнее» мог бы написать только сам автор.
Читатель может попытаться пересказать мысль автора "своими" словами, стараясь выстроить их по правилам (шаблонам?). Например: 
(Замерев) В ожидании раската хриплого генеральского голоса, (все сильнее) удивляясь затянувшейся паузе девушка –связистка опасливо взглянула на Захарова. Тот стоял, приложив платок к глазам.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Мне кажется, длинновато получилось, растянуто,  поэтому экспрессии меньше. В начале предложения чисто книжный оборот, он хорош для описаний, но не для изображения событий. К тому же девушка - не главный персонаж, ее лучше поставить в начало предложения (как эпизод), а то она в героя так превратится. Впрочем, моя  основная идея - это оправдать нестандартный прием сочетания причастия и деепричастия, о котором был вопрос.

Comment: И еще. Тут дело не в том, что читатель будет разбирать грамматику - обычному читателю нужна именно художественность текста. Грамматику разбирают редакторы, которые проявляют желание подогнать текст писателя под правила и стандарты, а вот это уже плохо. Художественый образ главнее правил, но при этом  все авторские варианты должны объясняться, а не быть произвольными. Здесь тоже нужна определенная строгость.

Comment: Sharon, с Вами нельзя не согласиться. Вставляя в живую ткань авторского текста «подразумеваемые» слова и укладывая этот текст в шаблонные конструкции мы получаем пересказ, лишенный живости, образности, сочности писательского слога и потому, никакие переложения не могут оказаться «лучше».

Comment: Прекрасно, что мы поняли друг друга.

Answer (score 1):

Причастный и деепричастный обороты можно было бы теоретически соединить союзом `и`, только если бы причастный оборот имел достаточно сильный смысловой оттенок обстоятельства или деепричастный—определения, что сделало бы их однородными членами предложения.

Однако если попробовать поиграться с такими конструкциями, то быстро становится понятно, что язык сам пытается изменить фразу так, чтобы оба оборота стали одинаковыми по типу.

Например, "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup> (утверждены в 1956 году Академией наук СССР, Министерством высшего образования СССР и Министерством просвещения РСФСР — как раз актуальное издание для вашего примера) предлагают такой пример для причастного оборота, который имеет "кроме значения определения, также обстоятельственный оттенок":

`Погруженный в свои мысли, Чечевицын ничего не ответил на этот вопрос.` (Чехов)

Если попробовать воткнуть в эту фразу однородный деепричастный оборот, получается что-то такое:

`Погруженный в свои мысли и перебирая в голове события прошедшего дня, Чечевицын ничего не ответил на этот вопрос.`

Вроде как и работает фраза, а слух режет. Хочется либо сменить причастный на деепричастный, либо наоборот:

`Погруженный в свои мысли и перебирающий в голове события прошедшего дня, Чечевицын ничего не ответил на этот вопрос.`

`Погрузившись в свои мысли и перебирая в голове события прошедшего дня, Чечевицын ничего не ответил на этот вопрос.`

Но даже если мы допускаем подобное сочетание, то, на мой взгляд, `удивленная длинной паузой` слабо смахивает на обстоятельство, а `ожидая раската хриплого генеральского голоса`—на определение.

Так что как обосновывается в данном случае пунктуация мне непонятно—по всем правилам тут напрашивается перестроение предложения в такое, в котором союза нет, а обороты находятся по разные стороны подлежащего.

Что касается запятой перед тире, то тут всего четыре варианта:

1. §198: встретились тире и запятая на стыке двух конструкций;

> – Здорово живешь, соседка, – поздоровался Петро, касаясь рукавицей шапки.

2. §175: комбинация отделяет часть предложения, привязанную с помощью повторяющегося слова;

> Я знала очень хорошо, что это был муж мой, не какой-нибудь новый, неизвестный человек, а хороший человек, – муж мой, которого я знала, как самоё себя.

2. §176: комбинация отделяет группу придаточных от главного предложения, подчеркивая распадение целого на две части;

> Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам.

3. §177: комбинация находится внутри периода, где она, по определению [периода], разделяет его на часть с повышением в тоне и часть с понижением в тоне.

> В 1800-х годах, в те времена, когда не было еще ни железных, ни шоссейных дорог, ни газового, ни стеаринового света, ни пружинных низких диванов, ни мебели без лаку, ни разочарованных юношей со стеклышками, ни либеральных философов-женщин, ни милых дам-камелий, которых так много развелось в наше время, – в те наивные времена, когда из Москвы, выезжая в Петербург в повозке или карете, брали с собой целую кухню домашнего приготовления, ехали восемь суток по мягкой, пыльной или грязной дороге и верили в пожарские котлеты, в валдайские колокольчики и бублики, – когда в длинные осенние вечера нагорали сальные свечи, освещая семейные кружки из двадцати и тридцати человек, на балах в канделябры вставлялись восковые и спермацетовые свечи, когда мебель ставили симметрично, когда наши отцы были еще молоды не одним отсутствием морщин и седых волос, а стрелялись за женщин и из другого угла комнаты бросались поднимать нечаянно и не нечаянно уроненные платочки, наши матери носили коротенькие талии и огромные рукава и решали семейные дела выниманием билетиков, когда прелестные дамы-камелии прятались от дневного света, – в наивные времена масонских лож, мартинистов, тугендбунда, во времена Милорадовичей, Давыдовых, Пушкиных, – в губернском городе К. был съезд помещиков, и кончались дворянские выборы.

Тут как раз последний вариант, хотя и не очень качественно реализованный—тон пытается нарастать в первой части, но она слишком короткая чтобы накопить достаточно напряжения при прочтении.

В результате, когда мы переходим через разделитель периода, особого выпуска этого напряжения не случается.

---

1. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации : Утв. Акад. наук СССР, М-вом высш. образования СССР и М-вом просвещения РСФСР. – Москва : Учпедгиз, 1956. – 176 с.

Comment: *только если бы причастный оборот имел достаточно сильный смысловой оттенок обстоятельства* - в исходном примере он и имеет  смысл обстоятельства причины. Иначе вообще трудно сказать, что он там вообще делает в предложении.

Comment: *а что, причастные обороты, которые функционируют как определения теперь запрещено использовать?* - с чего бы такой вывод? Я во всяком случае такого не говорил. Я говорил, что в **конкретном** предложении причастный оборот по его смыслу может быть только обстоятельством причины. Причины того, что связистка смотрела **с опаской**. При ином толковании фраза  теряла бы связность и сам смысл появления в ней этого причастного оборота был бы совершенно непонятен.

Comment: @Heagon Я отметила всех участников дискуссии. И Вас благодарю (с бонусом — за объем, отстаивание своего мнения и мне не совсем понятное _переходим через разделитель периода_).